# SQL: Selecting Average Hour From DateTime

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am looking to determine the average time a customer takes an action. I have 2 columns, customer_id and Action_timestamp.

Sample data:

```
customer_id  |  Action_timestamp
1            | 2016-11-21T21:56:49.0000000
1 | 2016-12-07T00:19:34.0000000
1 | 2016-11-21T21:43:19.0000000
2 | 2016-11-21T21:53:39.0000000
3 | 2016-11-21T21:57:33.0000000
3 | 2016-10-01T16:24:10.0000000
```

I want to group by the customer_id and find the average time from the date timestamp. Average time would equal the sum of all hours (OK to ignore minutes) divided by the count of rows each customer ID appear in.

I'm looking to return:

```
1 | 14
2 | 21
3 | 18
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: also define what average time in your context is.

Comment: Thanks for the tips - added both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select customer_id,avg(extract(hour from Action_timestamp)) from <table_name> group by customer_id;
```